# How can i Create a new folder when a user is created just for the user

Tags: php, html, mysql, directory

How can i Create a new folder when a user is created just for the user. So he can upload videos/images and have access only to his videos/images. i Tried mkdir() it creates a brand new directory structure. I want it to create a new folder in the "uploads" directory for every user created so he can upload videos/images into his own folder and them play them on the web.

```
<?php
     if($count == 0){

      if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_pass) VALUES('$uname','$email','$upass')"))
      {
       ?>
       <script>alert('successfully registered ');</script>

    <?php
    $structure = "uploads/UserFolder";
    if(!mkdir($structure, 0777,true)){
     die('Did not create a folder.');

    }

      }
      else
      {
       ?>
       <script>alert('error while registering you...');</script>
       <?php
      }  
     }
     else{
       ?>
       <script>alert('Sorry Email ID already taken ...');</script>
       <?php
     }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Maybe instead of `UserFolder` you should use the user ID from the DB if such exists? So instead of "uploads/UserFolder" you can use "uploads/".$userID. You should not try to create the same folder for every new user. Instead you should create a new unique folder for every new user.

Comment: when i added "uploads/".$userID. it dies and prints "Did not create a folder."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give write permission for uploads(777 is better) folder. then create sub folders with user unique ids.I hope it will help.